# XPath wildcards and contains() function usage

Tags: xml, xpath, contains

I have a problem using XPath and contains function. Imagine the XML example below:

```
   <doc>  
     <Test>
       <Name>1 Pre Histoy</Name>
       <Type>Known</Type>
       <Data>
          <Name>Dinasor</Name>
          <Name>Fish</Name>
      </Data>
      </Test>

      <Test>
        <Name>1 Post Histoy</Name>
        <Type>Known</Type>
        <Data>
          <Name>Human</Name>
          <Name>Dog</Name>
        </Data>
     </Test>

      <Test>
        <Name>1 Post Histoy</Name>
        <Type>UNKNOWN</Type>
        <Data>
          <Name>Human</Name>
          <Name>Dog</Name>
        </Data>
     </Test>  

  </doc>
```

So what I want to do is returning all `<Name>` texts within `<Data>` node, with following criteria:

1. `doc//Test/Name` should contain "Pre" text
2. `doc//Test/Type` should be "Known"

What I need is a query like this but so far I couldn't manage it

```
/doc//Test[Name contains(.,'Pre') and Type='Known']/data//Name
```

Any help and tips will be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't that be Data with a capital D at the end?

Comment: I suppose so, if you count the first character as one of the ends...

Comment: Sorry that one was just example. Capital D wouldnt do something either.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
/doc/Test[contains(Name, "Pre") and Type="Known"]/Data/Name
```

Here is a working example implemented in Javascript to take advantage of [StackOverflow's Runnable Code Snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

```js
function fu(path){
  var output = "";
  var results =  document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE  , null);
  while(nextResult = results.iterateNext()){ output += nextResult.outerHTML + "\n"; }
  return output;
}

document.body.innerText = fu('//doc/Test[contains(Name, "Pre") and Type="Known"]/Data/Name');
```

```html
<doc>  
 <Test>
   <Name>1 Pre Histoy</Name>
   <Type>Known</Type>
   <Data>
      <Name>Dinasor</Name>
      <Name>Fish</Name>
  </Data>
  </Test>

  <Test>
    <Name>1 Post Histoy</Name>
    <Type>Known</Type>
    <Data>
      <Name>Human</Name>
      <Name>Dog</Name>
    </Data>
 </Test>

  <Test>
    <Name>1 Post Histoy</Name>
    <Type>UNKNOWN</Type>
    <Data>
      <Name>Human</Name>
      <Name>Dog</Name>
    </Data>
 </Test>  

  </doc>
```

Comment: @Jon: Thanks! This is [my second XPath answer](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxpath%5D+user%3A106224) ever :)

Comment: Clearly you pick it up faster than I do ;)

Comment: I have tested for the same reason, it was worked.Thanks! Mine is /PlaceSearchResponse/result[contains(name,'Bimeks')]/geometry